# How to plot an algebraic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, graphing-functions

Is there an algorithm to plot an algebraic curve $f(x, y)=0$ ?

If the degree of $f$ is 4 or less, then there is a formula for the solution, so I think I can plot the curve (I don't know there is a better algorithm or not). What about the general case?

Comment: Wikipedia's ["Implicit curve" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_curve) describes some algorithms in the "Visualization..." section. That should get you started.

Comment: Are you looking for algorithms to find a (local) parameterization?

Comment: @doetoe If there is such an algorithm, I want to know that, but approximation by a finite set of points is also acceptable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes there are many ways to do this. Here is one particular way:

1. Guess one root.
2. Apply some numerical optimization to find your way towards one true root from your guess.
3. When close enough to a root, iterate the following:

   1. Take a small steps in the tangent direction.
   2. Take steps in the gradient direction.

If your surface is in many dimensions you may want to somehow systematically generate some kind of a local ON gradient-tangent basis.

One good thing about this approach is that you get to choose your guess freely, you can pick for example a point close to the center of the screen or whichever area you want to visualize.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Wolfram Alpha, it is quite easy : you just as for the contour "line" where $f(x,y)=0$.

I added a small example [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5Bx%5E5+-+x%5E3+y%5E4+%2B+y%5E6+%3D%3D+0%2C+%7Bx%2C+-10%2C+10%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-20%2C+20%7D%5D).

Comment: I don't want a  product. I want to know an algorithm.